# iOS app to scan and recognize receipts

Tags: ios, ocr, scanning, image-recognition

We have an older neat receipts scanner that is starting to fail.  One of the problems I've had with Neat Receipts is that the software isn't magical enough.

Seems to me that you *should* be able to scan a receipt, and with the first one from a particular company tell the software,

- This is a gas receipt.
- This number is the amount of fuel
- This is the price per liter.
- This number is the payment
- This is the last 4 digits of the credit card
- This is the date.  It is yyyy/mm/dd

And on a different one:

- This is a grocery receipt
- This block is all line items.  Add codes to Save On Foods
- This block is the total

etc.

Ideally some of this can be crowd sourced.  Once ONE person does this for Save On Foods, or Warburg Gas, then it's available for all.

It doesn't have to be a scanner.  It could just as well be an iPhone app that I take a picture of the receipt.

Comment: Have you found anything?